# Is ActiveRecord table_name thread safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord

I have a multi-threaded Rails application (using Sidekiq), and in each of the threads I am setting table_name for SomeModel to a different table name

Example:

```
Thread 1:
SomeModel.table_name = "temp_table1"

Thread 2:
SomeModel.table_name = "temp_table2"
```

Is this thread-safe?

In other words, if I set it to "temp_table1" in thread 1, is there anyway for thread 2 or another thread to see this change, or is it only applicable for thread 1?

I'm using vanilla Ruby.

Comment: MRI? JRuby? Rubinious? Also, you **should not** do this. Never.

Comment: I'm using vanilla Ruby. Not JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a variable in MRI is thread safe. Once you update the value at thread 1, **all** other threads will see this same value.

Comment: actually in my scenario, I don't want table_name to be changed for all other threads :(

Comment: then you don't want to do this. run queries manually, trying to monkey patch `table_name` to do what you want to do is not a good option.